# Can i use string literal inside for loop?

Tags: java, string

I have coded like follows,

```
for(int i=0 ; i<n; i++){

String a = someObject.getFirstName(); //may not come same value..
doManipulationon(a);
}
```

During code review, people asked me to remove the string literal `a` and use `someObject.getFirstName()` directly for manipulation. They afraid that string object will be created in heap on every iteration.

Is this the correct way?

I thought assigning the getter into a string variable gives code more readable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First there is no string literal here.

A string literal is a string expression enclosed in double quotes, like "dog".

Your reviewers are stating that they do not like the temporary variable `a` used to hold an expression that you are manipulating in the very next line.

Apparently they want you to say

```
doManipulationon(someObject.getFirstName());
```

Removing temporary variables leads to more compact code.  This is usually, but not always, a good idea.  You can use temporary variables when your "intermediate expression" has an interesting meaning, but in your case, using the name `a` was not helpful.  You could have said

```
String firstname = someObejct.getFirstName();
```

In long expressions, especially, assigning partial results to variables that are given meaningful names does add to readability.

Oh, and as to their comment about new string objects being added to the heap in your example --- no, none will.

Answer (score 2):

Are you asking whether you can write that loop as:

```
for(int i=0; i < n; i++) {
    doManipulation( someObject.getFirstName() );
}
```

? If so, definitely yes. But, `a` there is *not* a String literal -- it's just a variable name. Using it will just push a reference to the underlying String (which is on the heap) onto the stack -- and that'll happen whether you have a variable `a` or not (that is, it'll happen in the version of the code I wrote, too). And even if it didn't, pushing a reference onto the stack is so cheap it doesn't matter. But either way, the String is going to be on the heap, because Strings are objects, and objects live on the heap.

So it's just stylistic, and if you find it more readable to assign the String to a variable, then by all means, do. It can also make it easier to debug, since you can put a breakpoint at the `doManipulation` line and see input before you go into that function. (You can do that even without the assignment, but it's just slightly less convenient.)

Comment: I like your answer, but you there is one thing wrong to it: Strings (and objects in general) are not always on the heap - interned Strings (such as String literals) live in the PermGen, which is not part of the region called heap (see http://stackoverflow.com/a/2051778/1162168)

Comment: @MichaelSchmeißer Yeah, and what we call "the heap" isn't even a [heap data structure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_(data_structure)) in Java! With generational GCs (which is what HotSpot uses), newly allocated objects live in a chunk of memory which is closer to a stack that except that you can only clear it (not pop individual items). Still, I was trying to keep things simple for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

> They afraid that string object will be created in heap on every
>   iteration.

If that's what they are really concerned about, they don't know what they are talking about. A new string is created on the heap *if and only if* `someObject.getFirstName()` creates a new String. Creating a temporary variable to hold a *reference* does not create a new String.

The temporary variable costs one stack slot. All stack slots are allocated at the beginning of the method, not when used. So the space cost of the temporary variable is 4-8 bytes; the time cost is a store and a load; and the heap cost is zero.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following command to check out the bytecode:

```
>javap -c -classpath /path/to/your/class/file classname
```

There difference is that your code has two bytecode instructions that are :

```
astore_2 // store a reference into local variable 2

aload_2  // load a reference onto the stack from local variable 2
```

So, your code is okay and What it exactly does is not like others said

> "They afraid that string object will be created in heap on every
>   iteration."